# why doesn't .h file recognize the _cplusplus version I am using?

Tags: c++, arm, keil

My `.h` file has this code for the __cplusplus version in use:

```
 #define CPP14_SUPPORTED (__cplusplus >= 201402L)

 #if CPP14_SUPPORTED
    #define IS_CPP14_SUPPORTED 1 // BUT THIS IS GREYED OUT in the .h file!
 #endif
```

The main issue is that all my .h files do not see this definition as well.

When I use the definition `IS_CPP14_SUPPORTED` in my `.cpp` file it shows that it is true and not greyed out.

I am using keil uvision5 IDE

Comment: Probably because it's not a valid code https://wandbox.org/permlink/VU1gQolBAx3JedZG

Comment: Do you have error messages from the compiler? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: There is no error, the problem is in how things are displayed

Comment: You might need to tell your IDE what C++ version to assume. If there is no "C++ version" option to set, try passing a preprocessor definition like `__cplusplus=201402L`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#define CPP14_SUPPORTED __cplusplus >= 201402L
#if CPP14_SUPPORTED
   #warning "cpp14 supported"
#else
   #warning "Cpp14 not supported"
#endif
```

With `-std=c++14` it prints

```
<source>:3:5: warning: #warning "cpp14 supported" [-Wcpp]
    3 |    #warning "cpp14 supported"
      |     ^~~~~~~
```

With `-std=c++11` it prints

```
<source>:5:5: warning: #warning "Cpp14 not supported" [-Wcpp]
    5 |    #warning "Cpp14 not supported"
      |     ^~~~~~~
```